# How do I make a VBA function output the result of an If, then statement to a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time ever doing any coding, so I am sorry if it is awful and could be much better. My problem is that I just get a #VALUE error in the cell when I try to use this function and I do not know why.
The program is supposed to take whichever information that the user inputs and decide whether or not this specific connector will work for the designated inputs. Whether the connector works is based on which cables can be used and the type of connector input by the user.

```
Function CONNECTOR1(Cable As Double, Connector As String, Row As Double) As String
    CableI = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").String
    ConnectorI = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").String
    MaxdBLossI = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4").Value
    ConnectorTypeI = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E4").String
    If IsEmpty(CableI) = True And IsEmpty(ConnectorI) = True And Not IsEmpty(MaxdBLossI) And Not IsEmpty(ConnectorTypeI) Then
        If ConnectorTypeI = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & Row).Value And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("N3:N500"), Cable) Then
            CONNECTOR1 = Connector
        End If
    ElseIf IsEmpty(ConnectorTypeI) = True And CableI = Cable Then
        CONNECTOR1 = Connector
    ElseIf CableI = "" Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("N3:N500"), Cable) Then
            CONNECTOR1 = Connector
        End If
    ElseIf ConnectorTypeI = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & Row).Value And CableI = Cable Then
        CONNECTOR1 = Connector
    Else
        CONNECTOR1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("O" & Row).ClearContents
    End If
End Function
'The goal of this code is for it to decide based on which inputs the user has given, if a certain connector will satisfy the criteria
'Connectors only work for a specific number of cables, so this set of code is only for a connector that works with one cable
'CableI is a cable part number input by the user
'ConnectorI is a connector part number input by the user
'MaxdBLossI is an input amount of acceptable signal loss
'ConnectorTypeI is an input for the specific type of connector needed`
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `{Range}.String`. Invoke that function from the immediate pane (Ctrl+G), you'll get an actual VBA error. also note that a function meant to be invoked from a worksheet cell (i.e. a UDF) **cannot modify any other cells**, so `.ClearContents` can't be something the function does (not to mention `.ClearContents` isn't a function so that `Else` branch is assigning the return value to ...a method call, which won't compile.

Comment: All of your If Statements except the last one end in `CONNECTOR1 = Connector` which is just returning the value of the Connector parameter you are inputing into the function.

Comment: I want the If, then, to return the value of Connector if the conditions are met. What I want is for the function to output the Connector variable if any of the sets of conditions are met. I don't know how to accomplish that. Thank you all for your comments!